# Sonarscanner MSBuild tool is not running in pipeline - Jenkins

Tags: asp.net, jenkins, msbuild, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I am running this following pipeline which has stage "Build + Sonarscanner Analysis" for dotnetcore 2.2

**The stage is set as follows**

1. I have installed the tool in Global Configuration as suggested by
   Sonarqube Documentation

[image]

2. Defined the tool in the environment as following

```
// Tools
        MSBUILD_SQ_SCANNER_HOME = tool name: 'Scanner_for_MSBuild_4.7', type: 'hudson.plugins.sonar.MsBuildSQRunnerInstallation'
```

3. Pipeline Stage

```
stage ('Build + SonarQube analysis') {
            agent {
                docker { 
                    image 'mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:2.2'
                }
            }
            steps {
                dir ("app") {
                    withSonarQubeEnv('local') {
                        sh "dotnet ${MSBUILD_SQ_SCANNER_HOME}/SonarScanner.MSBuild.dll begin /k:\"Testing-Local\""
                        sh "dotnet build ${env.DotnetProjectName}"
                        sh "dotnet ${MSBUILD_SQ_SCANNER_HOME}/SonarScanner.MSBuild.dll end"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

***Result***

I am getting the SonarScanner.MSBuild.dll is not executable as seen below

[image]

***Verfication***

1. The dll exists and the permissions is assigned to Jenkins
2. The dll is executable
3. The dll when run manually in that path - it runs

[image]

4. Directly added the path for the dll, It has the same result

```
stage ('Build + SonarQube analysis') {
            agent {
                docker { 
                    image 'mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:2.2'
                }
            }
            steps {
                dir ("app") {
                    withSonarQubeEnv('local') {
                        sh "dotnet /var/lib/jenkins/tools/hudson.plugins.sonar.MsBuildSQRunnerInstallation/Scanner_for_MSBuild_4.7/SonarScanner.MSBuild.dll begin /k:\"Testing-Local\""
                        sh "dotnet build ${env.DotnetProjectName}"
                        sh "dotnet var/lib/jenkins/tools/hudson.plugins.sonar.MsBuildSQRunnerInstallation/Scanner_for_MSBuild_4.7/SonarScanner.MSBuild.dll end"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this,

**1. Installed the SonarScanner for dotnetcore in Jenkins Tools**

The path for the sonarscanner will be the same as before

*Default Path*

> /var/lib/jenkins/tools/hudson.plugins.sonar.MsBuildSQRunnerInstallation/Scanner_for_MSBuild_4.7/SonarScanner.MSBuild.dll

**2. Initialize the tool in Jenkinsfile**

```
// Tools
MSBUILD_SQ_SCANNER_HOME = tool name: 'Scanner_for_MSBuild_4.7', type: 'hudson.plugins.sonar.MsBuildSQRunnerInstallation'
```

```
stage ('Build + SonarQube analysis')
      agent {
             docker { 
                  image 'mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:2.2'
                  args '-v ${MSBUILD_SQ_SCANNER_HOME}:/opt/sonarscanner'
                }
            }
            steps {
                dir ("app") {
                    withSonarQubeEnv('local') {
                        sh "dotnet /opt/sonarscanner/SonarScanner.MSBuild.dll begin /k:\"Testing-Local\""
                        sh "dotnet build ${env.DotnetProjectName}"
                        sh "dotnet /opt/sonarscanner/SonarScanner.MSBuild.dll end"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

**How it works?**

1. I am mounting the sonarscanner to the official docker image at the path /opt/sonarscanner/
2. With the mounted file as an argument for docker container during initialization, now the dll is avaliable for the docker dotnet command

Comment: Hi @armourshield, can you please help me to understand how can I install SonarScanner for dotnetcore in jenkins tool. Is there any plugin for it. I found only the plain SonarScanner plugin

Comment: @SVD it depends on what host OS you are using for Jenkins, for example in the above example I was using Linux so used the sonarscanner installed using the plugin and gave the path inside the dotnetcore docker container, remember SonarScanner.MSBuild.dll needs dotnet CLI for it to work. As in the answer you can see -v mounting the jenkins plugin to container. You can use the link to set things up (https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analysis/scan/sonarscanner-for-jenkins/)